# core data fetch request crash without error log

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Contact entity has a many to one relationship to user, which has a userID field

Contact has a status string attribute that can be either 'approved', 'rejected', 'pending' etc

favorite boolean attributes

```
+ (NSSet *)fetchContactsWithUserID:(NSString *)userID approvedOnly:(BOOL)approvedOnly favoriateOnly:(BOOL)favoriateOnly {


    NSString *predString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(user.userID = %@)", userID];
    if (approvedOnly) {
        predString = [predString stringByAppendingString:@" AND (status = approved)"];
    }
    if (favoriateOnly) {
        predString = [predString stringByAppendingString:@" AND (favorite = YES)"];
    }

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predString];


    return [self private_fetchEntitiesWithName:@"Contact" predicate:pred];
}

+ (NSSet *)private_fetchEntitiesWithName:(NSString *)name predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:[self private_context]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    if (predicate) {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self private_context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; //CRASH ON THIS LINE!!!!!!
    return [NSSet setWithArray:fetchedObjects];
}
```

stack trace:

[image]

There is no error logged out (i already enabled nszombie)

Comment: Please add exception breakpoint

Comment: yes the exception breakpoint is on

Comment: There must be an error log... From what I see an obj_c MSG send error. So probably you send a method to the wrong object

Comment: @Volker you mean the core data is correct?

Comment: Press "Continue" a couple of times. The exception message won't be logged when the exception breakpoint is triggered

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (status == approved) (problem on RHS)'

Comment: @MatthiasBauch get the error log, thanks. but not sure what's wrong with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@"(status = approved)"` is not a valid predicate. If approved is a string your predicate string should be `@" AND (status = \"approved\")"` or `@" AND (status = 'approved')"`.

If you use a string literal directly in a predicate you have to enclose it in quotes.

Strings that are not enclosed in quotes are treated as keys by the NSFetchRequest.
This is done because you can actually check if two attributes are equal by using a predicate that compares those two, e.g.`@"attribute1 = attribute2"`.

---

If you use a predicate format that contains `%@`, NSPredicate will automatically add quotes if the object you want to use as argument is a NSString.

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foo = %@", @"Bar"];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foo = Bar"];

NSLog(@"%@", p1);
NSLog(@"%@", p2);
```

yields:

```
xxx[4673:70b] foo == "Bar"
xxx[4673:70b] foo == Bar
```

Comment: interestingly, [NSPredicate predicateWithString:@"xxx AND status = %@", @"approved"] works

Comment: Because NSPredicate will add the quotes for you. NSLog the predicate to see